# Solving $e^{x^2}+xe^{x}=5e^{x}$ for $x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, problem-solving

Analytical solution not numerical solution. I tried to solve for $x$ in the equation $e^{x^2}+xe^{x}=5e^{x}$ I  did

$e^{x^2}+xe^{x}=5e^{x}$

$e^{x^2}=(5-x)e^{x}$

$1=(5-x)e^{x-x^2}$

$xe^{4x}=x(5-x)e^{x(5-x)}$

Apply Lambert Function

$W(xe^{4x})=x(5-x)$

but it's wrong, can anyone help.

Comment: $$5-x=e^{x^2-x}\ge0\implies x\le5$$

Let $f(x)=e^{x^2-x}+x-5$ which is clearly increasing 

$$f(1)=1+1-5<0$$

$$f(2)=e^2+2-5>0$$

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't $e^{(x^2)}$ instead of $e^{x^2}$?

Comment: Were you told that an analytical solution is possible ?

Comment: The trick would work with $4e^{x^2}+xe^x=5e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that we could have any analytical solution but we can obtain accurate formal *approximations*  for the zero's of function
$$f(x)=e^{x^2}+e^x (x-5)$$

For the negative solution, use a Taylor expansion around $x=-1$. For example
$$f(x)=\left(e-\frac{6}{e}\right)+\left(-\frac{5}{e}-2 e\right) (x+1)+\left(3
   e-\frac{2}{e}\right) (x+1)^2-\left(\frac{1}{2 e}+\frac{10 e}{3}\right)
   (x+1)^3+O\left((x+1)^4\right)$$

Now perform a series reversion to obtain, as an *approximation*,
$$x=-\frac{59178+1026 e^2+79470 e^4+3225 e^6+4042 e^8-44 e^{10}}{6 \left(5+2
   e^2\right)^5}$$ which is $-0.924458$ while the numerical solution is $x=-0.924461$.

Simpler would be to consider the function
$$g(x)=x^2-x-\log(5-x)$$ which shows a minimum at
$$x_*=\frac{1}{4} \left(11-\sqrt{89}\right)$$ Performing a series expansion around this point gives
$$x=x_*\pm\sqrt{-2\frac {f(x_*)} {f''(x_*)}}$$ that is to say
$$x=\frac{11-\sqrt{89}}{4} \pm \frac{9+\sqrt{89}}{4} \sqrt{ \frac{9 \sqrt{89}-83+8 \log \left(\frac{1}{4}
   \left(9+\sqrt{89}\right)\right)}{89+9 \sqrt{89}}}$$ which gives $x_1\sim -0.922081$ and  $x_2\sim 1.70509$ while the numerical solution are $x_1=-0.924461$ and  $x_2=1.70145$.

Now, one single iteration of Newton method gives an explicit result (too long to type it) and the numerical values are
$$x_1=-0.9244634\qquad \text{and} \qquad x_2=1.7014554$$ to be compared to the "exact" values
$$x_1=-0.9244612\qquad \text{and} \qquad x_2=1.7014503$$